# plotting jpg file on the lowest layer of spplot

Tags: r, gis, jpeg, r-sp

I am creating a floorplan of a house, here are what I have now:

- a jpg file which is the scanned version of a paper copy of the floorplan
- 3 shp files showing the house, room and beds

I figured how to create a spplot using the 3 shp files by `sp.layout`, now I need to plot the jpg on the back of the spplot also. How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code you have.

Comment: If I had shapefiles and a jpeg, I'd simply setup the coordinates with `plot()`, then use `rasterImage()` to draw the image and `polygon()` to draw the shapes. I don't use `grid`, but in theory you should be able to use `grid.raster` and then `spplot`.

Answer (score 0):

`Orcs` package provides `rgb2spLayout` function to convert RGB raster into a format, which can be  used in `sp.layout` argument of `spplot` function.

Please see the code below:

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(Orcs)
library(rgdal)

b <- brick( system.file("pictures/Rlogo.jpg", package="rgdal"))
lout <- rgb2spLayout(b)

df <- data.frame(dat = rnorm(100, 50, 10),
                 x = rnorm(100, 100, 50),
                 y = rnorm(100, 100, 50))
coordinates(df) <- ~x+y

spplot(df, sp.layout = lout)
```

Output (pay attention to colour scaling):

[image: plot]